# Should Deb package maintainer script use Bash or Sh

Tags: bash, shell, deb

In Deb package maintainer script, e.g. postinstall, prerm, etc. I think we often use /bin/sh as shell script interpreter. However, /bin/sh might be different on different distribution or user preferences. For example, Ubuntu link /bin/sh to /bin/dash, or some use might link to /bin/tcsh.

There are two type of syntax I encountered that might failed if user change shell to tcsh.

1) set -e # tcsh can't understand this.

2) > /dev/null 2>&1 # ambiguous redirection.

The first thought is to remove (1), and change (2) to >& /dev/null. However, I found in most maintainer script, the 'set -e' line are presented.

Now, I'm not sure should

a) I just fix all the problem and use /bin/sh 
b) change to use /bin/bash
c) ignore tcsh case

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Thank you.
Jack

Comment: I presume the debian packaging policy has guidelines for this that indicate whether using `set -e`, etc. are valid in those locations and what shells can possibly be `/bin/sh` on a conforming system. Have you looked?

Comment: `set -e` just a common way or practice in script I found. I have looked document about packaging deb, but it's not saying too much. However, @Tonin do provide a good document about Debian policy which clear explain the script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-scripts) doesn't force you to use `/bin/sh` as shell, you can use any other one provided you name it correctly (with the [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)) and it is available on the system you try to install to (which limits you to default provided shells if you use it in preinst scripts).

But the Debian policy tells you that `/bin/sh`, whatever that really is, will always implement the SUSv3 Shell Command Language (i.e.: a shell that is POSIX compliant) and some additional features.  That is what you can rely on for your maintainer scripts.

On Debian, `/bin/sh` was `/bin/bash` until Lenny.  From Squeeze, it is now `/bin/dash`.  See the [Debian wiki for more information](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell).

On Debian or any derivatives, if `/bin/sh` is actually linked to `/bin/tcsh` it will be a local setting changed by the local administrator. That will probably not only break your scripts but many others.  The Debian policy document actually tell maintainers to avoid `csh` and `tcsh` as scripting languages.

In conclusion, I think you shouldn't bother about your scripts being compatible with `tcsh` and the best practice would be to only use `/bin/sh` for all your packaging needs.

Always refer to the full [Debian policy document](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks for this document! It's very useful as a guild line.